# What does “behind the spin” mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Today I read in my company newsletters
“Behind the spin”
our company and our strategy

Checking the meaning of the spin, the only logical meaning I found was story ( but involving deceiving for entertainment) so I am not really sure what do they mean by “behind the spin” and if spin-story what is the difference?

Comment: Was this the title of an article, like "Behind the Spin - Our Company and Strategy?" What was the full context? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: the title is “behind the spin”

Comment: and the context is about our company and strategy

Answer (score 2):

"Spin" is a term from politics:

> [**spin**, noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spin#Noun)
> 3. (*countable, uncountable*) A favourable comment or interpretation intended to bias opinion on an otherwise unpleasant situation.
> *Try to put a positive spin on the disappointing sales figures.*
> *The politician was mocked in the press for his reliance on spin rather than facts.*
> Synonym: propaganda

So "behind the spin" can mean something like "the real information about our public image," with **behind** meaning "being reason for or explanation of."

The term is usually used in a negative sense so it seems strange for a company to use it so matter-of-factly about themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Not deceiving for entertainment (I'm not sure where you found that definition). "Spin" is deceiving, in a political or public-relations context, in order to make your position seem better. It is trying to bias opinion.

> Try to put a positive spin on the disappointing sales figures.
>
> The politician was mocked in the press for his reliance on spin rather than facts.  (examples from Wiktionary)

"Behind the spin" therefore means the truth about the company.  It probably relates to a marketing or public relations department, whose job is (partly) to put a positive spin on news from the company.